# Rails 3:How to Sum up Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have model Register which marks the attendance of user based on department and group.Each user has a department and group.

Register Model

```
date:date , departmentid:string , groupid:integer , one:integer , two:integer
```

among the above fields "one and two" are time slots(say: from 9-14 , 14-18 ).Attendance are marked such that user belongs to current date , groupid , departmentid.So for same day there will be multiple entries with groupid ,departmentid and their attendance.

Sample Register table below

[image]

I want to find no. of users attented per day.
currently i have tried

```
@register = Register.where(:date=>"2012-12-28").sum(:one)
```

it is getting well ,but i want to find like,

```
@register = Register.where(:date=>"2012-12-28").sum(:one , :two ,:three)
```

is it possible....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this ?

```
class Register < AR:Base

...

  def self.attendee_count(slot) # slot is :one or :two
    scoped.group(:date ).sum(slot)
  end

end

Register.where(:date => Date.today).attendee_count(:one)
Register.where(:date => Date.today, :departmentid => "DP14").attendee_count(:two)
```

Comment: thanks for the above code.....Is it possible to find like this ..  Register.where(:date => Date.today, :departmentid => "DP14").attendee_count(:one , :two , :three)...if so what should i write in model.

Comment: Something like this : `[:one, :two, :three].map{|slot| Register.where(:date => Date.today, :departmentid => "DP14").attendee_count(slot)}.sum` according to [the sum method of enumerable](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum). This will make 3 queries, though. I don't think you can do it with a single query easily.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

<strike>Department.group(:date).sum(:one, :two)</strike>

Comment: "departmentid" is just a field in User table.There is no assosiation between User and Department.Hope your above code will only find the no of entries,not the sum of all entries in table field "one or two"

Comment: I have updated my Post it is not Department ,it is Register actually.sorry..Your code will become  Register.group(:date).sum(:one ,:two)..

Comment: It Works with Register.group(:date ).sum(:one) ,but it only counts the first date (say 2012-12-20).How to find by given date